# Extjs Tree context menu mixes on second open

Tags: extjs, contextmenu

Below, When I close and reopen the window, 'projeler', contextmenu of the tree damages itself. When I reopen the window, only first item damages itself. It seems like there are two labels mixed together. I tried to delete 'generalCreationButtonStatus' but I got same error on first item of the menu.
  Could you please help?

Ext.define('MyDesktop.Projeler', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.Module',

```
requires: [

    'Ext.util.Format',
    'Ext.grid.Panel',
    'Ext.grid.RowNumberer',
    'Ext.tree.*', 
    'Ext.data.*', 
    'Ext.tip.*'
],

id:'tree-projeler',

init : function(){
    this.launcher = {
        text: 'Projeler',
        iconCls:'projectManage-shortcut'
    };
},

createWindow : function(){


    var projectCreationWin = new Ext.Window({
        layout:'form',
        title: 'Proje Oluşturma',
        closeAction:'hide',
        plain: true,
        width: 250,
        height: 200,
        modal : true,
        resizable:false,    
        items:[
            {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Proje Kodu',
            emptyText: 'Proje Kodu Yazınız...',
            name:'projectCreationWin_projectCode_name',
            id:"projectCreationWin_projectCode_id",
            width: 100,
            anchor: '100%'
            },
              {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Proje Adı',
            emptyText: 'Proje Adı Yazınız...',
            name:'projectCreationWin_projectName_name',
            id:"projectCreationWin_projectName_id",
            width: 100,
            anchor: '100%'
            },

    ],
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Oluştur',
            handler: function(){
               var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
               var projectCode= Ext.getCmp("projectCreationWin_projectCode_id");
               var projectCode= projectCode.getValue();           
               var projectName= Ext.getCmp("projectCreationWin_projectName_id");
               var projectName= projectName.getValue();

               Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'phps/treeloader.php',
                    params:{
                        'process':'addNode',
                        'subProccess': 'addProject',
                        'code':projectCode,
                        'name':projectName,
                        'node': selectedNode[0].data.id,
                        'depth': '1'           
                    },
                    success: function(response, options) {
                     Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirilmiştir !');                   
                    },
                    failure: function(response, options) {
                       Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Gerçekleştirilemedi!');  
                    } 
                });           

            }
        },{
            text:'Vazgeç',
            handler: function(){

            }
        }],


        listeners:{
            beforeshow:function(){

            }
        }
    })

    var contractCreationWin = new Ext.Window({
        layout:'form',
        title: 'Kontrat Oluşturma',
        closeAction:'hide',
        plain: true,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        modal : true,
        resizable:false,    
        items:[
            {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Kontrat Numarası',
            emptyText: 'Kontrat Numarası Yazınız...',
            name:'contractCreationWin_contractNo_name',
            id:"contractCreationWin_contractNo_id",
            width: 100,
            anchor: '100%'
            },
            {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Sas Numarası',
            emptyText: 'Sas Numarası Yazınız...',
            name:'contractCreationWin_PONo_name',
            id:"contractCreationWin_PONo_id",
            width: 100,
            anchor: '100%'
            },
            {
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        fieldLabel: 'Single Column',
        columns: 1,
            items: [
                {
                boxLabel: 'PAC', 
                name: '222', 
                inputValue: 1,
                id: 'contractCreationWin_RadioPAC_id',
                },
                {
                boxLabel: 'PAT', 
                name: '222', 
                inputValue: 2, 
                id: 'contractCreationWin_RadioPAT_id',

                },

            ]
        }

        ],
          buttons: [{
            text: 'Oluştur',
            handler: 
                function(){
                   var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                   var contractNo= Ext.getCmp("contractCreationWin_contractNo_id");
                   var contractNo= contractNo.getValue();           
                   var customerPO= Ext.getCmp("contractCreationWin_PONo_id");
                   var customerPO= customerPO.getValue();

                   var ifPAC = Ext.getCmp('contractCreationWin_RadioPAC_id');
                   var ifPAC= ifPAC.getValue();

                   if(ifPAC == true){
                        var contractType = 'PAC';
                   }else{
                        var contractType = 'PAT';
                   }



                   Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'phps/treeloader.php',
                        params:{
                            'process':'addNode',
                            'subProccess': 'addContract',
                            'code':contractNo,
                            'name':customerPO,
                            'parentId': selectedNode[0].data.id,
                            'depth': '3',
                            contractType: contractType ,          
                        },
                        success: function(response, options) {
                         Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirilmiştir !');                   
                        },
                        failure: function(response, options) {
                           Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Gerçekleştirilemedi!');  
                        } 
                    });           




            }
        },{
            text:'Vazgeç',
            handler: function(){

                alert(this.getValue(true));

            }
        }],


        listeners:{
            beforeshow:function(){

            }
        }
    })


    function generalCreationButtonStatus(){
        if (projelerTree.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
           var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

           if(selectedNode[0].data.depth==0){
                Ext.getCmp('tree-context-proje-olustur').show();
           }else{
                Ext.getCmp('tree-context-proje-olustur').hide();
           }

           if(selectedNode[0].data.depth==1){
                Ext.getCmp('tree-context-faz-olustur').show();

           }else{
                Ext.getCmp('tree-context-faz-olustur').hide();

           }

           if(selectedNode[0].data.depth==2){
                Ext.getCmp('tree-context-kontrat-olustur').show();

           }else{
                Ext.getCmp('tree-context-kontrat-olustur').hide();

           }

           if(selectedNode[0].data.depth==3){
                Ext.getCmp('tree-context-saha-olustur').show();
           }else{
                Ext.getCmp('tree-context-saha-olustur').hide();
           }
        }




         }




    var projelerTereeRclckMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
        listeners:{
            beforeShow: function(){
                projelerTereeRclckMenu
                generalCreationButtonStatus();
            }
        },
        items: [
            { 
            text: 'Sil',
            id: 'tree-context-sil', 
            handler : function(){ alert('Sil butonuna tıklandı'); },

            },
            {
            text: 'Proje Oluştur',
            id: 'tree-context-proje-olustur', 
            handler : function(){
                projectCreationWin.show();
                }

            },
            {
            text: 'Faz Oluştur',
            id: 'tree-context-faz-olustur', 
            handler : function(){
               var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

               Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'phps/treeloader.php',
                    params:{
                        'process':'addNode',
                        'subProccess': 'addPhase',
                        'parentId': selectedNode[0].data.id,
                        'depth': '2'           
                    },
                    success: function(response, options) {
                     Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirilmiştir !');                   
                    },
                    failure: function(response, options) {
                       Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Gerçekleştirilemedi!');  
                    } 
                });

                }

            },
            {
            text: 'Kontrat Oluştur',
            id: 'tree-context-kontrat-olustur', 
            handler : function(){
                contractCreationWin.show();
            },

            },
            {
            text: 'Saha Oluştur', 
            handler : function(){ alert('Sil butonuna tıklandı'); },

            id: 'tree-context-saha-olustur',
            }

        ]
    });


    var projelerTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', { 
        proxy: { 
             type: 'ajax', 
             actionMethods: 'post',
             url: 'phps/treeloader.php',
             extraParams: {
                process:'callNode',


             } 
         }, 

         root: { 
             text: 'Root Node', 
             id: '0',
             parentid:'0',
             expanded: false,

         }, 
         folderSort: true, 
         sorters: [{ 
             property: 'text', 
             direction: 'ASC' 
         }] 
     }); 


   var projelerTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel', { 
        store: projelerTreeStore, 
        id:'projelerTree-id',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(), 
        height: 300, 
        width: 250, 
        title: 'PMT Ağaç Yapısı',

        tbar : [{
            text:'Yenile',
            handler: function(){


        },
        { 
         text: 'add node', 
         handler: function() { 
             if (projelerTree.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) { 
                 var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection(); 
                 Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Add Node', 'Please enter node text:', function(btn, text){ 
                     if (btn == 'ok'){ 

                         Ext.Ajax.request({ 
                             url: 'phps/treeloader.php', 
                             params: {
                                nodetext: text, 
                                parentid : selectedNode[0].data.id,
                                depth:  selectedNode[0].data.depth,
                                process: 'addNode'

                             }, 
                             success: function(response){ 
                                 var id = response.responseText; 

                                 if (id > 0) { 
                                     selectedNode[0].set('leaf', false); 
                                      alert('success'); 
                                     selectedNode[0].appendChild({ 
                                         leaf: true, 
                                         text: text, 
                                         id: id,

                                     });          

                                 } 
                             } 

                         }); 
                     } 
                 }); 
             } else { 
                 Ext.MessageBox.alert('Uyarı!', 'Lütfen node eklemek istediğiniz yeri seçiniz!'); 
             } 
         } 
        }],

        listeners: {
            render: function() {
                Ext.getBody().on("contextmenu", Ext.emptyFn, null, {preventDefault: true});

            },
            itemcontextmenu : function( view, record, item, index, event){
            x = event.browserEvent.clientX;
            y = event.browserEvent.clientY;

            projelerTereeRclckMenu.showAt([x,y]);
        },





            click: {
                element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
                fn: function(){ 


                }
            },
            dblclick: {
                element: 'body', //bind to the underlying body property on the panel
                fn: function(){
                    Ext.getBody().on("contextmenu", Ext.emptyFn, null, {preventDefault: true});


                }
            },

        } 
        });

    var desktop = this.app.getDesktop();
    var win = desktop.getWindow('tree-projeler');
    if(!win){

        var win = desktop.createWindow({
            id: 'window-projeler',
            closeAction: 'hide',
            title:'Projeler',
            width:600,
            height:400,
            iconCls: 'projectManage-shortcut',
            animCollapse:false,
            border: false,

            hideMode: 'offsets',

            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                projelerTree,    
            ]
        });

    }
    return win;
},
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting id's of context menü items, then I needed to devide 'projelerTereeRclckMenu' accoeding to depth of tree. And I finally prepared if condition under riğght click function that shows needed context menü accordin to depth of tree:

/*!
 * Ext JS Library 4.0
 * Copyright(c) 2006-2011 Sencha Inc.
 * licensing@sencha.com
 * http://www.sencha.com/license
 */

Ext.define('MyDesktop.Projeler', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.Module',

```
requires: [
    //'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
    'Ext.util.Format',
    'Ext.grid.Panel',
    'Ext.grid.RowNumberer',
    'Ext.tree.*', 
    'Ext.data.*', 
    'Ext.tip.*'
],

id:'tree-projeler',

init : function(){
    this.launcher = {
        text: 'Projeler',
        iconCls:'projectManage-shortcut'
    };
},

createWindow : function(){

    var projectCreationWin = new Ext.Window({
        layout:'form',
        title: 'Proje Oluşturma',
        closeAction:'hide',
        plain: true,
        width: 250,
        height: 200,
        modal : true,
        resizable:false,    
        items:[
            {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Proje Kodu',
            emptyText: 'Proje Kodu Yazınız...',
            name:'projectCreationWin_projectCode_name',
            id:"projectCreationWin_projectCode_id",
            width: 100,
            anchor: '100%'
            },
              {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Proje Adı',
            emptyText: 'Proje Adı Yazınız...',
            name:'projectCreationWin_projectName_name',
            id:"projectCreationWin_projectName_id",
            width: 100,
            anchor: '100%'
            },

        ],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Oluştur',
            handler: function(){
               var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
               var projectCode= Ext.getCmp("projectCreationWin_projectCode_id");
               var projectCode= projectCode.getValue();           
               var projectName= Ext.getCmp("projectCreationWin_projectName_id");
               var projectName= projectName.getValue();

               Ext.Ajax.request({
                    url: 'phps/treeloader.php',
                    params:{
                        'process':'addNode',
                        'subProccess': 'addProject',
                        'code':projectCode,
                        'name':projectName,
                        'node': selectedNode[0].data.id,
                        'depth': '1'           
                    },
                    success: function(response, options) {
                     Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirilmiştir !');                   
                    },
                    failure: function(response, options) {
                       Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Gerçekleştirilemedi!');  
                    } 
                });           
            }
        },
        {
            text:'Vazgeç',
            handler: function(){
            }
        }],

        listeners:{
            beforeshow:function(){

            }
        }
    })

    var contractCreationWin = new Ext.Window({
        layout:'form',
        title: 'Kontrat Oluşturma',
        closeAction:'hide',
        plain: true,
        width: 300,
        height: 300,
        modal : true,
        resizable:false,    
        items:[
            {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Kontrat Numarası',
            emptyText: 'Kontrat Numarası Yazınız...',
            name:'contractCreationWin_contractNo_name',
            id:"contractCreationWin_contractNo_id",
            width: 100,
            anchor: '100%'
            },
            {
            xtype:'textfield',
            fieldLabel: 'Sas Numarası',
            emptyText: 'Sas Numarası Yazınız...',
            name:'contractCreationWin_PONo_name',
            id:"contractCreationWin_PONo_id",
            width: 100,
            anchor: '100%'
            },
            {
            xtype: 'radiogroup',
            fieldLabel: 'Single Column',
            columns: 1,
                items: [
                    {
                    boxLabel: 'PAC', 
                    name: '222', 
                    inputValue: 1,
                    id: 'contractCreationWin_RadioPAC_id',
                    },
                    {
                    boxLabel: 'PAT', 
                    name: '222', 
                    inputValue: 2, 
                    id: 'contractCreationWin_RadioPAT_id',
                    //checked: true
                    },

                ]
            }
        ],
        buttons: [{
            text: 'Oluştur',
            handler:
                function(){
                    var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    var contractNo= Ext.getCmp("contractCreationWin_contractNo_id");
                    var contractNo= contractNo.getValue();           
                    var customerPO= Ext.getCmp("contractCreationWin_PONo_id");
                    var customerPO= customerPO.getValue();

                    var ifPAC = Ext.getCmp('contractCreationWin_RadioPAC_id');
                    var ifPAC= ifPAC.getValue();
                    //alert(JSON.stringify(ifPACPAT));
                    if(ifPAC == true){
                         var contractType = 'PAC';
                    }else{
                         var contractType = 'PAT';
                    }

                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'phps/treeloader.php',
                        params:{
                            'process':'addNode',
                            'subProccess': 'addContract',
                            'code':contractNo,
                            'name':customerPO,
                            'parentId': selectedNode[0].data.id,
                            'depth': '3',
                            contractType: contractType ,          
                        },
                        success: function(response, options) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirilmiştir !');                   
                        },
                        failure: function(response, options) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Gerçekleştirilemedi!');  
                        } 
                  });           
                }
        },
        {
            text:'Vazgeç',
            handler: function(){
                alert(this.getValue(true));
             }
        }],
        listeners:{
            beforeshow:function(){

            }
        }
    })

    function generalCreationButtonStatus(){
        if (projelerTree.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) {
        }
    }
    //function RCLCK(){

    var projelerTereeRclckMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
        listeners:{
            beforeShow: function(){
                //projelerTereeRclckMenu
                generalCreationButtonStatus();
            }
        },
        items:[
            { 
            text: 'Sil',
            name: 'tree-context-sil',
            listeners: {
                beforeshow:
                function(){
                    var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    alert(selectedNode[0].data.depth);
                    if(selectedNode[0].data.depth==1){
                        this.hide;
                        alert('222');
                    }else{
                        this.show();
                    }    
                },
            }, 
            handler : function(){ alert(JSON.stringify(projelerTereeRclckMenu.items[0])); },
                            },
            {
            text: 'Proje Oluştur',
            name: 'tree-context-proje-olustur', 
            handler : 
                function(){
                    projectCreationWin.show();
                }
                       },


                   ]
    });

    var fazlarTereeRclckMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
        listeners:{
            beforeShow: function(){
                generalCreationButtonStatus();
            }
        },
        items:[
            { 
            text: 'Sil',
            name: 'tree-context-sil',
            listeners: {
                beforeshow:
                function(){
                    var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    alert(selectedNode[0].data.depth);
                    if(selectedNode[0].data.depth==1){
                        this.hide;
                        alert('222');
                    }else{
                        this.show();
                    }    
                },
            }, 
            handler : function(){ alert(JSON.stringify(projelerTereeRclckMenu.items[0])); },

            },
            {
            text: 'Faz Oluştur',
            name: 'tree-context-faz-olustur', 
            handler : 
                function(){
                    var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    Ext.Ajax.request({
                        url: 'phps/treeloader.php',
                        params:{
                            'process':'addNode',
                            'subProccess': 'addPhase',
                            'parentId': selectedNode[0].data.id,
                            'depth': '2'           
                        },
                        success: 
                            function(response, options) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Başarıyla Gerçekleştirilmiştir !');                   
                            },
                        failure: 
                            function(response, options) {
                                Ext.Msg.alert('Dikkat!','İşleminiz Gerçekleştirilemedi!');  
                            } 
                    });
                }

            },

        ]
    });

    var kontratlarTereeRclckMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
        listeners:{
            beforeShow: function(){
                generalCreationButtonStatus();
            }
        },
        items:[
            { 
            text: 'Sil',
            name: 'tree-context-sil',
            listeners: {
                beforeshow:
                function(){
                    var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    alert(selectedNode[0].data.depth);
                    if(selectedNode[0].data.depth==1){
                        this.hide;
                        alert('222');
                    }else{
                        this.show();
                    }    
                },
            }, 
            handler : function(){ alert(JSON.stringify(projelerTereeRclckMenu.items[0])); },

            },
            {
            text: 'Kontrat Oluştur',
            name: 'tree-context-kontrat-olustur', 
            handler : 
                function(){
                    contractCreationWin.show();
                },

            },

        ]
    });

    var sahalarTereeRclckMenu = new Ext.menu.Menu({
        listeners:{
            beforeShow: function(){
                generalCreationButtonStatus();
            }
        },
        items:[
            { 
            text: 'Sil',
            name: 'tree-context-sil',
            listeners: {
                beforeshow:
                function(){
                    var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();
                    alert(selectedNode[0].data.depth);
                    if(selectedNode[0].data.depth==1){
                        this.hide;
                        alert('222');
                    }else{
                        this.show();
                    }    
                },
            }, 
            handler : function(){ alert(JSON.stringify(projelerTereeRclckMenu.items[0])); },
            //iconCls:'icon-grid-del'
            },
            {
            text: 'Saha Oluştur', 
            handler : 
                function(){ 
                    alert('Sil butonuna tıklandı'); },

                    name: 'tree-context-saha-olustur',
            }

        ]
    });    

    var projelerTreeStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.TreeStore', { 
        proxy: { 
            type: 'ajax', 
            actionMethods: 'post',
            url: 'phps/treeloader.php',
            extraParams: {
                process:'callNode',
            } 
        }, 
        root: { 
            text: 'Root Node', 
            id: '0',
            parentid:'0',
            expanded: false,

        }, 
        folderSort: true, 
        sorters: [{ 
            property: 'text', 
            direction: 'ASC' 
        }] 
    }); 

    var projelerTree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',{ 
        store: projelerTreeStore, 
        id:'projelerTree-id',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(), 
        height: 300, 
        width: 250, 
        title: 'PMT Ağaç Yapısı',
        tbar : [{
            text:'Yenile',
            handler: 
                function(){
                //projelerTree.getView().refresh(); 
                 //projelerTree.treeRefresh();                    
                }

        },
        { 
        text: 'add node', 
        handler: 
            function(){ 
                if (projelerTree.getSelectionModel().hasSelection()) { 
                    var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection(); 
                    Ext.MessageBox.prompt('Add Node', 'Please enter node text:', function(btn, text){ 
                        if (btn == 'ok'){
                                                        Ext.Ajax.request({
                                url: 'phps/treeloader.php', 
                                params: {
                                    nodetext: text, 
                                    parentid : selectedNode[0].data.id,
                                    depth:  selectedNode[0].data.depth,
                                    process: 'addNode'

                                }, 
                                success: function(response){ 
                                    var id = response.responseText; 
                                    if (id > 0){
                                        selectedNode[0].set('leaf', false); 
                                        alert('success'); 
                                        selectedNode[0].appendChild({ 
                                            leaf: true, 
                                            text: text, 
                                            id: id,
                                        });          
                                       ();                                    
                                     } 
                                } 
                            }); 
                        } 
                    }); 
                }else{ 
                    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Uyarı!', 'Lütfen node eklemek istediğiniz yeri seçiniz!'); 
                } 
            }//handler 
        }],
        listeners: {
            render: 
                function() {
                    Ext.getBody().on("contextmenu", Ext.emptyFn, null, {preventDefault: true}
                );

            },
            itemcontextmenu : 
                function( view, record, item, index, event ){

                    x = event.browserEvent.clientX;
                    y = event.browserEvent.clientY;

                    var selectedNode = projelerTree.getSelectionModel().getSelection();

                    var depth = selectedNode[0].data.depth;

                    if(depth==0){
                        projelerTereeRclckMenu.showAt([x,y]);                            
                    }else if(depth ==1){
                        fazlarTereeRclckMenu.showAt([x,y]);
                    }else if(depth == 2){
                        kontratlarTereeRclckMenu.showAt([x,y]);
                    }else if(depth == 3){
                        sahalarTereeRclckMenu.showAt([x,y]);
                    }


            },
            click: {
                element: 'el', //bind to the underlying el property on the panel
                fn: function(){                     }
            },
            dblclick: {
                element: 'body', //bind to the underlying body property on the panel
                fn: 
                    function(){
                        Ext.getBody().on("contextmenu", Ext.emptyFn, null, {preventDefault: true});
                    }
            },

        } 
    });

    var desktop = this.app.getDesktop();
    var win = desktop.getWindow('tree-projeler');
    if(!win){
        var win = desktop.createWindow({
            id: 'window-projeler',
            listeners:{
                beforeshow:function(){
                projelerTereeRclckMenu.hide();
                                    }   
            },

            //closeAction: 'destroy',
            title:'Projeler',
            width:600,
            height:400,
            iconCls: 'projectManage-shortcut',
            animCollapse:false,
            border: false,
                           closeAction: 'hide',
            hideMode: 'offsets',

            layout: 'fit',
            items: [
                projelerTree,    
            ]
        });

    }
    return win;
},//Createwindow function ens here
```

});